# How to install php7 cli along with existing php 5.5

Tags: php, command-line-interface, php-7, fedora

I want to install PHP7-cli without disturbing the existing PHP 5.5. There are many projects running on PHP 5.5 and I want to make another CLI application using PHP7.0.

The server is Linux Fedora 5.*

PHP 5.5 FSM is being used currently. There is no Composer on the server.

Comment: You should try out docker

Answer (score 1):

I've not got much experience with Fedora, but you can install PHP 7 and just run your cli scripts by referencing the PHP binary directly.

Ie: `/usr/bin/php7.2 path/to/script.php` (bin path may vary on Fedora, my experience is only in Ubuntu!)

If, after the install, PHP 7.2 is the default, you can use `update-alternatives` to set 5.5 back as default.

`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5`

Also, if the 7.2 Apache module has been enabled you can run something like

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2 && sudo a2enmod php5.5
sudo service apache2 restart
```